# NServiceBus. When there are too many messages?

Tags: transactions, integration, nservicebus, messaging

We are looking into using NServiceBus for data integration. We receive incoming xml files with data and need to process them into several subsystems/databases. Our initial approach was not to put data in message body, but extract it to database and then send message with File ID.

Now I'm thinking of sending each row of data in the message body (copy fields to message properties) and process each row independently.

What I'm concerned with this approach is that will that design will be maintainable with large amount of incoming data? Lets say millions records daily? Does it make sense to produce so many massages, or maybe it's better put them into some batches? Does it make sense to put data in message at all or it's better to work with IDs?

Comment: I'd say batchas rather than single messages if at all possible, but why are you using messaging for syncing data? are capturing the events and doing some other work? usually databases have a set of tools for data synchronization. If you go down the messaging route i'd consider what dose the message act as command or event? and based on that decision model what is going to be in the message.

Comment: NServiceBus by itself is able to easily keep up with millions of messages a day. Performance shouldn't be your primary concern here.

Answer (score 1):

Евгений,

Would using DataBus be an option for you? You get the file, there's no really need to decompose it and send record-by-record to other systems since it sounds like those systems are interested in entire file. Also, it will reduce substantially number of messages that you'll have to send/process.
Look into documentation here, it might be what you're looking for. http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/attachments-databus-sample

Sean

Answer (score 0):

Our application uses NServiceBus and MSMQ and we process 50-100 thousand messages every our using a single server and a single thread.

I would use 2 types of messages:

1. Decompose message, which would read the master record ID and decompose it in individual messages
2. Item Process message, where I would use at least 5 threads and stick to insert type of database processing

Feel free to create some sort of service that saves the initial data in one chuck to the database and simply passes the ID of the record in the database as message type #1 which then in turn would create all the messages of type 2. This ensures isolation and the use of transactions.

You could become fancy and use Sagas but you don't really need to

http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/sagas-in-nservicebus